# Angular Tags disrupting CSS stylings

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, angular

I have a project being built with the Angular 2 framework. The custom angular tags (`<my-app>`, `<my-whatever-component>` etc.) keep disrupting the css output. When the HTML is directly on the `index.html` file (not in any component whatsoever) the CSS loads alright.

I have debugged and have come to the certain conclusion that the custom angular tags are the cause of the issue.

What do i do to change this behavior? How can i make the custom Html tags vanish after the view is rendered ? This will prevent Hierarchical CSS rules from breaking.

Edit 1 : I forgot to mention the CSS is custom (Free bootstrap admin template thingy) so i can't (more like i don't want to) tweak it.

Comment: Look at the DOM. Write CSS that matches it.

Comment: @Quentin Please see edit

Comment: You can tweak the css without modifying the original just create the css file for your component and overwrite  the styles, every component css file  will not leak it's styles to others components, it is only used in the component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set View Encapsulation Types, More information [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html#view-encapsulation-types)

```
@Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'my-zippy',
   templateUrl: 'my-zippy.component.html',
   styles: [`
    .zippy {
      background: green;
    }
   `],
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None //No Shadow DOM at all. Therefore, also no style encapsulation.
})
```

**EDIT**

As a workaround you can use an attribute selector in your component like

```
selector: '[my-component]'
```

and then use it like

```
<div my-component>Hello My component</div>
```

This way you can skip component tags from your HTML and can apply hierarchical css.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. View Encapsulation has to do with keeping style rules only on a component. What i really want is for the custom tag " < my-zippy >" to sort of dissapear  once the view has been rendered. This will prevent Hierarchical CSS rules from breaking.

Comment: @omo_prodigi check my EDIT section, may be this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example through pluncker or similar?
Are you using the [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) bootstrap.js or the [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)?
If you are just using the straight up twitter bootstrap you will have problems using any of the bootstrap components that are implemented in javascript.

Hope that helps